Can I replace a 12 V 190 Ah battery with two 6 V 200 Ah batteries in 48 V system?
The battery bank is made of 4 each 12 V 190 Ah AGM lead acid batteries. One died, and I couldn't find the replacement easily. Instead, I found some 6 V 200 Ah batteries.
Could I hook them up and be OK? Should I put the two 6 V all the way on - terminal or + terminal or in between 12 V? [pic1]
When the battery bank is being charged, how does each battery receive the energy (electrons?)? The charge controller pushes nominal 48 V, but how does it ends up being divided the 48 V in to each appropriate voltage for each individual batteries? [pic1]
At night, when the inverter pulls the energy from the battery, electrons moves from negative to load to positive?
So then during the day when the solar array is charging the battery, is the electron being pushed into the positive?
So then what happens when there is a draw from a load at the same time?
Charge controller, inverter, and battery bank shares common negative bus bar and positive bus bar, so if charge control is pushing electron into positive bus bar, it would take electron into positive side of the inverter as well? [pic2]



all the batteries are agm

Connecting batteries without matching will cause more voltage to be across different cells because of internal resistance differences, don't to this, you could reduce the lifetime of destroy the batteries

Ideally, all batteries in a bank should be the same make and model, and usage history.  If one battery in your bank has failed, the others are likely nearing end-of-life as well, so you should replace the whole bank.


Can I replace one 12 V 190 Ah with two 6 V 200 Ah in 48 V system?

Yes, you can.

how does each battery receives the energy (electrons?)?

Energy and electrons are not the same thing. So I'll answer both.

Current (“electrons”)
Like all circuits, the current flows in a loop.
Current flows from the positive terminal of the charger, into the positive terminal of the most positive battery, out of its negative terminal and into the positive terminal of the next battery, and so forth, until it exits the negative terminal of the most negative battery, finally returning to the negative terminal of the charger.

Power
Power is voltage times current. The current is the same in each battery (as explained above). Each battery has a voltage of 12 V. As the voltage and current of each battery are identical, therefore, each battery receives the same amount of power from the charger.

Energy
Energy is power times time. As the charger is on for a given time, and all the batteries receive power for that same time, therefore, all the batteries receive the same energy during a charge cycle. However, when a lead acid battery is full, it uses that energy not to charge but to vent.



how does it ends up being divide the 48 V in to each appropriate voltage

The charge doesn't set the voltage of a battery, each battery does. Each battery sets its own voltage, based on the cell chemistry, its state of charge, the temperature, and how much current is going in or out. Having said that, the charger does set the maximum voltage for the entire bank of batteries.

electron moves from negative to load to positive?

Please please please: forget about electrons! The sooner you forget all about “electron flow” the sooner you'll understand electricity. Think it terms of “current”, not “electron flow”.
Current goes in a circle. I described that circle above. While charging, current goes into the positive of the battery and out the negative; it goes out of the positive of the charger and into the negative. While discharging, current goes out of the positive of the battery and into the negative; it goes out of the positive of the load and out the negative.

what happens when there is a draw from a load at the same time?

No problem.
The power is the difference between source power and load power. If the source can provide more power than the load wants, the remainder goes into the battery. If the load draws more current than the source can provide, the battery makes up the difference and power the load partially.
